# ajaxfileupload does not display "Select Files" dialog

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am developing an internal web application which collects various images and paints them onto a larger image automatically.  I am having trouble with the ajaxFileUpload control from Microsoft's AJAX toolkit.

Within the page, the user has the option to fill in an ID number into a text box and click a button to grab some text data (metadata for the image) and populate a couple of text boxes/dropdown lists.  The user also has the option to click a button to upload images from their local system for processing.  The ajaxFileUpload control is on an UpdatePanel.

When the user uses the "populate" feature to retrieve the metadata and then chooses to upload images, the "Select File" button does not trigger the Open File dialog on the local system.

When the user first attempts to upload images before retrieving metadata, the "Select File" button pops the Open File dialog to allow the user to choose the desired files.

The ajaxFileUpload control works as expected in the first case; I assume that if I can actually choose the files to upload, the remainder of the process will work.

What code would be required to posted to attempt to resolve this?  The ASPX?  The backend VB?

Markup:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat = "server" ID = "upMain" >
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label runat = "server" ID = "lblImageBuilderTitle" Text = "Image Builder" CssClass = "panelTitle" />
        <asp:Table runat = "server">
            <asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableCell HorizontalAlign = "Right" Width = "10%">
                    <asp:Label runat = "server" Text = "JTN: " />
                </asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TextBox runat = "server" ID = "tbJTN" /><asp:Button runat = "server" ID = "btnPopulate" Text = "+" />
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableCell HorizontalAlign = "Right" Width = "10%">
                    <asp:Label runat = "server" Text = "Job Ref: " />
                </asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TextBox runat = "server" ID = "tbJobRef" />
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableCell HorizontalAlign = "Right" Width = "10%">
                    <asp:Label runat = "server" Text = "Customer: " />
                </asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:DropDownList runat = "server" ID = "ddlImageBuilderCustomer" />
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableCell HorizontalAlign = "Right" Width = "10%">
                    <asp:Label runat = "server" Text = "Type: " />
                </asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:DropDownList runat = "server" ID = "ddlImageBuilderType" AutoPostBack = "true" />
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableCell HorizontalAlign = "Right" Width = "10%">
                    <asp:Label runat = "server" Text = "Email to Deana: " />
                </asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:CheckBox runat = "server" ID = "cbEmailDeana" Checked = "true" />
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableCell HorizontalAlign = "Right" Width = "10%">
                    <asp:Label runat = "server" Text = "Email to Amy: " />
                </asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:CheckBox runat = "server" ID = "cbEmailAmy" />
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableCell HorizontalAlign = "Right" Width = "10%">
                    <asp:Label runat = "server" Text = "Rego Branding: " Visible = "false" />
                </asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:CheckBox runat = "server" ID = "cbRegoBranding" Visible = "false" />
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableCell ColumnSpan = "2" HorizontalAlign = "Center">
                    <asp:Label runat = "server" Text = "Images: " /><br />
                    <asp:GridView runat = "server" ID = "gvImages" AutoGenerateColumns = "false" AutoGenerateSelectButton = "false">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label runat = "server" ID = "lblOriginalName" Text = "<%# Bind('original_filename') %>" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Button runat = "server" ID = "btnRowUp" CommandName = "Reorder" CommandArgument = "Up" />
                                    <asp:Button runat = "server" ID = "btnRowDown" CommandName = "Reorder" CommandArgument = "Down" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                        <EmptyDataTemplate>No images uploaded.</EmptyDataTemplate>
                    </asp:GridView>
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
        </asp:Table>
        <asp:ModalPopupExtender runat = "server" ID = "mpePopulate" TargetControlID = "btnPopulateDummy" PopupControlID = "pnlPopulate" BackgroundCssClass = "modalBackground" />
        <asp:Button runat = "server" ID = "btnPopulateDummy" CssClass = "invisible" />
        <asp:ModalPopupExtender runat = "server" ID = "mpeUpload" TargetControlID = "btnUpload" PopupControlID = "pnlUpload" CancelControlID = "btnUploadClose" BackgroundCssClass = "modalBackground" />
        <asp:Button runat = "server" ID = "btnUpload" Text = "Upload Images" />
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID = "gvPopulate" EventName = "SelectedIndexChanged" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID = "btnUploadClose" EventName = "Click" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID = "gvImages" EventName = "DataBound" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID = "ajuImageUpload" EventName = "UploadComplete" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code-Behind:

```
Private Sub ImageBuilder_PreRender(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.PreRender
    Dim dtIBImages As New DataTable
    If IsPostBack = False Then
        BindCustomerDDL("ImageBuilder")
        BindCategoryDDL("ImageBuilder")
        BindTemplatesDDL()
        'Session("dtIBImages") = Nothing

        'dtIBImages.Columns.Add("id")
        'dtIBImages.Columns.Add("original_filename")
        'dtIBImages.Columns.Add("image_filename")
        'dtIBImages.Columns.Add("disposition")

        '    Session("dtIBImages") = dtIBImages
    Else
        dtIBImages = Session("dtIBImages")
        gvImages.DataSource = dtIBImages
        gvImages.DataBind()
    End If
    dtIBImages = Session("dtIBImages")
    gvImages.DataSource = dtIBImages
    gvImages.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Comment: What the reason to put `AjaxFileUpload` control to UpdatePanel?

Comment: I am using that as the PopupControlID for a ModalPopupExtender.  It cleans up the interface.